# SQL JOINS just similar to excel vlook up but with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do 2 tables in SQL to form a third table. Example and the expected output is below

Table1

```
Date      CHI      HOS
1/1/1       1           a
1/1/1       2           b
2/1/1       1           a
3/1/1       3           c
```

Table2

```
Date       CHI  CRN
1/1/1      2    b
1/1/1      1    a
2/1/1      2    b
3/1/1      3    d
```

Table1 _new

```
Date      CHI      HOS  Hosp_new
1/1/1       1       a   a
1/1/1       2       b   b
2/1/1       1       a   a
3/1/1       3       c   d
```

The conditions are,

1. the unique key is `CHI`,
2. where `table1.Hos = table2.CRN` then `table1.HOS`
3. Where `table1.HOS <> table2.CRN` then `table2.CRN`
4. Where vlook up column in table1 CHI is not found in `table2` then `table1.HOS`
5. Create a new column `HOSP_new` and populate with the above
6. Its a 12 million rows file and I don’t want to have duplicate rows

Comment: CHI as duplicates. I.e. it's not a unique key.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: CHI is not unique, its the vlookup column

Comment: I am new to sql, i am using microsoft sql server management studio 18

Comment: Your first condition states *the unique key is CHI* which clearly it's not, and you then state it's not unique above, so is the data correct or not?

Comment: The data is correct, CHI is not unique key

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   select distinct t1.date, t1.chi, t1.hos, 
           case when t1.hos != t2.hos then t2.hos 
                else t1.hos end as Hosp_new 
     from table1 t1
     left join table2 t2 on t1.chi = t2.chi and t2.date = t1.date
```